# I can't understand how the double negation in sql works

Tags: sql

I have a hair product sql with product and condition and according to my knowledge I should use double negation for this type of question: "Which products use all ingridients?". How should I implement this question using double negation in sql?
[image: Here is the image of the model]

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.  Also, you should show what your tables look like.

Comment: Sample data from each table and the output you're trying to get from that data would be very helpful. Please [edit] to include it.

Comment: I don't think your model makes sense. The question in your question leads me to believe the product-condition relationship should be many-to-many.

Comment: Unless you need the product name, you only need the Manufacture and Ingredients tables to answer your question.  All the other tables are so much noise.  If you need the product name, you need the Product table too, of course.  The double negation sounds like the SQL implementation with NOT EXISTS?  What have you tried?  Always, what have you tried?  Trying to blind us with overly complex schema diagrams doesn't help; it is the SQL you've written that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `product` contains the condition or not.

I think you want something like this:

```
select p.product_id
from product p
group by p.product_id
having count(distinct condition_id) = (select count(*) from condition);
```

If condition contains the product/condition pairs:

```
select p.product_id
from condition p
group by p.product_id
having count(condition_id) = (select count(distinct condition_id) from condition);
```

Comment: Your magic 8 ball is strong. I don't think it is possible to make out anything from what little information is given in the question.